# cannot find folder after pear install

Tags: pear

i just installed the aws sdk on MacOs using the following command:
sudo pear install aws/sdk

it showed install successfully, but i cannot find the folder aws/sdk, where is it? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run:

```
$ pear list-files aws/sdk
```